# Populating the list with array of items

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dom, components

I have an array of items, and I have accessed one of the item's property to divide the items into two separate arrays. But when I try to populate the created array in the component of the DOM, gives an error

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {text, key, completedItem}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

The code is as follows:

```
 render() {

    let { items } = this.props;

    let listItems = items.map( (item) => {
        return (
                <TodoItem text={item.text}
                          key={item.key}
                          ID={item.key}
                          isComplete={item.completedItem}
                          onDelete={this.props.onDelete}
                          onEdit={this.props.onEdit}
                          handleComplete={this.props.handleComplete} />
        );
    });

    const revArray = listItems.reverse();
    console.log("Reversed Array  : ", revArray);

    const completedItems = items.filter((item) => {
        return ( item.completedItem == true );
    });
    console.log("Items Completed Array  : ", completedItems);

    const filterCompleted = items.filter((item) => {
        return ( item.completedItem == false );

    });
    console.log("Items not Completed Array  : ", completedItems);

    const resultArrItems  = [ ...filterCompleted, ...completedItems];
    console.log("Final Array    : ", resultArrItems);

    return (
        <div className="card card-body mt-5">
            <ul className="list-group my-3">
                <h3 className="text-capitalize text-center"> todo list </h3>
                <div>{resultArrItems}</div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I get the resultArrItems as of the exact order I need the array elements to be, when I view the array in the console, but the problem is I can't populate the component in the DOM with the resultArrItems. The error that I get is mentioned above. Is there any solution for this ...? and also what is the reason for this behavior ...?

Answer (score 0):

You only can represent elements in `render` or `return` with **JSX** syntax. Currently you are trying to display an array - `resultArrItems`. You need to use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and return inside a valid **JSX** element for each iteration.

You can try the following:

```
return <div className="card card-body mt-5">
   <ul className="list-group my-3">
       <h3 className="text-capitalize text-center"> todo list </h3>
       <div>
          {
             resultArrItems.map((e, i) => <div key={i}>
                {i} {/* here you can access also each elements properties */}
             </div>)
          }
       </div>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did something similar to what you said, I iterated through each item and extracted the text I needed to output